# How to download raw HTML from message on Google GMail?

Tags: gmail

I have an e-mail on GMail in HTML format. It is not attachment. The Google change few things before displaying it in the browser. **How can I download this HTML without any processing?**

---

P.S.

Looking at source code of an e-mail do not solve my problem. It is expected that the content will be encoded. In my case it is quoted-printable, but it is not the only option. Below is a short example.

```
--2JIROVSRMGPOVXOEVSHCLnhgwp
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div><span class=3D"highlight" style=3D"background-color:#00ff00">Test.</sp=
an><br></div>
--2JIROVSRMGPOVXOEVSHCLnhgwp--
```

Comment: So you're saying your email has Base64 encoded data instead of quoted-printable data for the HTML section of a multipart message?  (Which is not uncommon for larger emails with in-line items)  If so, that's what you'll see in the Raw of the message, you'll have to decode it to get the actual message contents in that section of the message.

Comment: @ThomasWard The problem I have is that I want Google to do this decoding.

Comment: Then that's not the raw msg in it's original raw format.  You need to contact Google to have them make a variant of "View Source" to do that.  Unfortunately theres nothing anyone other than Google can do to auto decode the encoded B64 text.

Answer (score 0):

**To download the raw html:**

- Open the Email
- Click the 3 dots, and click "show original"
- Find "`<!DOCTYPE html`" on the page
- Find "`</body></html>`" on the page
- Copy them, and everything between them

**Download the .eml:** (everything)

- Open the Email
- Click the 3 dots, and click "download email"

Comment: If I click to show origninal, the HTML is expected to be encoded. It is quoted-printable in my case.

Comment: what do you mean the html is expected to be encoded. can you send a screenshot of what the file looks like?

Comment: I cannot post a screen shot of the whole message. I have attached a short fragment in question.

Comment: can you upload a larger piece to paste bin? it doesn't necessarily have to be this specific email.

Comment: I have created a small mail and updated example. This is a whole HTML.

Comment: @FredTheDoggy in many cases, large-scale HTML stuff for size constraints, etc. is sometimes encoded (base64) and needs decoded first for use.  Typically, I've seen this in the raw form of the message, where the message is large and complex and for size purposes MTAs or email clients B64 encode the message part before transmitting.

Comment: you could do something as simple as: https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode it

Comment: yes but OP stated in comments on their question in reply to me they want *Google* to do that, which requires Google to write such a functionality.  They dont want the truly raw email source though at that point though they want the decoded source, which isnt what either of your methods will give (and no Google wont give you the non encoded form in 'view source' like OP wants)